# PHP try to querying MSSQL server

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql

i try to query MSSQL Server. The query is very simple but still get only errors. The version of PHP is  7.0.28 and code is here:

```
$serverName = "(local)";
/* Connect using Windows Authentication. */
try
{
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=mgm59ood", "sa", "********");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if ($conn)
    {
        $tsql = "select name from goods";
        $getResults = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);

        // Error handling

        if ($getResults == FALSE)
        {
            die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
        }
    }
}

catch(Exception $ex)
{
    die(print_r($ex->getMessage()));
}
```

In my browser throw exception in line with $getResults.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_query()
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\testwithsql\index.php:26 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\testwithsql\index.php on line 26

Please help me.

Comment: I think you want `$conn->query()` instead of `sqlsrv_query()` as you're using pdo extention to begin with.

Comment: You're using the wrong error function - `sqlsrv_errors()` - you need the pdo's - http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Thanks,
$conn->query() works, now i have no erorrs and will try to display data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install any driver for MS SQL?

If you didn't do it then:

- You can load it here - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55642
- And after that you need to add `extension=php_sqlsrv_xxx.dll` or `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_xxx.dll` into `php.ini` (look at `SQLSRV_Readme.htm`).

Demo with PDO and without PDO:

```
<?php

echo "Test with php_pdo_sqlsrv (PDO)\n";

$serverName = "(local)";
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName; Database=Test", "sa", "...");
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $tsql = "select 1 value";
    $result = $dbh->prepare($tsql)->execute();

    echo $result;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{  
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}


echo "\nTest with php_sqlsrv (not PDO)\n";

$serverName = "(local)";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Test", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"...");
try
{
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

    $tsql = "select 2 value";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
    $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result);
    echo $obj->value;   
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
    print_r($ex->getMessage());
}

?>
```

Comment: I add drivers from the link and same error. I add them before this post and if i had no drivers error will be different.

Comment: @spootles - Yes, you're right it wasn't a driver error. I've added two examples - with PDO and without PDO.